# Stocks sources of other website's showing on applying store switcher in admin

Tags: magento2.3, store-view, stock, inventory, multi-source-inventory

Ours is the multi website store(UAE and Oman), and each website is assigned its own stock source under Stores > Stocks

[image]

But when I Go to product edit, and switch store to Oman website, user is able to see the Inventory source of other websites also

[image]

[image]

Our client wants that user should only be able to see the stock sources which are assigned to that website (Oman in this case if I select one of the Oman Stores in store switcher. But it is also showing UAE stock sources also)

I checked few 3rd party extensions but none of them provides such a feature. Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?